# Councourse CI on Windows Git pull job always shows waiting for a suitable set of input versions

Tags: windows, git, pipeline, concourse

We installed Concourse CI on Windows 8 Machine.  Plan is to use this for a .NET project.  Basic samples are working fine.  However, when we tried with simple Git pull, the job is always in pending state.  And it shows following message:

[image: The job status]
The job definition is:

```
jobs:
- name: sourcejob
  plan:
  - aggregate:  
      - get: source  
        trigger: true 
resources:
- name: source
  type: git
  source:
      uri: git@github.com:xxxx/xxxxx.git
      branch: dev
      private_key: |
          -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
          --- trimmed ---
          kxZ6DGrV6BArxJVRnhRgY3CachoyQLd4yarxcIdPk9ncL/HZpr4NUywmBaSYLgEQ
          ---- trimmed ----
          4lto6OIq49FneZE1iCfzpELmw1OZnV7n2EqXRwFmM+YJGCrve3X9vqNUnjcxucsM
          -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0):

In your image that you posted, it also seems like your pipeline is paused. You can unpause it if you open the sidebar to your left and click the blue "play" button beside the name of your pipeline. It also seems like Concourse isn't able to fetch a version of your `sourcecode` resource. Also, is your worker a Windows worker? Because Windows workers don't have any of the basic resource types (like git) so it won't be able to fetch a new version of your git resource.

But if you are using a linux worker, you can run `fly check-resource --resource <pipeline-name>/sourcecode` to see if it is able to fetch a new version of your git resource. Maybe you can show me the error (if there is one) that it gives if you run this command?

Comment: Hi Clara,  Thanks for the clarity.  Yes, it is a Windows worker.  We originally planned to use Concourse CI for a .NET project on Windows platform.  Now, quite hesitated due to the level of support on Windows platform.  Do you have any other suggestion?